# Unable to edit configuration files in Marlin

Tags: editing, lpc

I have succesfully been using VS Code for a few months to edit configuration files in Marlin. However, I now find I cannot edit code at all, and I don't understand why. I have tried reinstalling VS Code, but no change.
As a work around, I have used Arduino IDE to edit the files, then because I have a 32 bit controller (SKR 1.4 Turbo), I used VS Code to build.
Can anyone tell me what might be preventing me from using VS Code as an editor?

Answer (score 1):

This can be because you project located at path, where VScode don't have permissions to edit files (for example somewhere at `C:\Program Files\Arduino`).
To fix this you can move your marlin project to "neutral waters" like your `Documents` folder
or
(not suggested) launch VScode with admin rights (right click on vscode shortcut -> Run as administrator)